# Deducing string transformation rules

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I have a set of pairs of character strings, e.g.:

abba - aba,
haha - aha,
baa - ba,
exb - esp,
xa - za

The second (right) string in the pair is somewhat similar to the first (left) string.

That is, a character from the first string can be represented by nothing, itself or a character from a small set of characters.

There's no simple rule for this character-to-character mapping, although there are some patterns.

Given several thousands of such string pairs, how do I deduce the transformation rules such that if I apply them to the left strings, I get the right strings?

The solution can be approximate, working correctly for, say, 80-95% of the strings.

Would you recommend to use some kind of a genetic algorithm? If so, how?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking here.  Statements like this "That is, a character from the first string can be represented by nothing, itself or a character from a small set of characters" are not making anything clear in this context.

Comment: Your example makes it seem like it could be as simple as using the string pairs themselves as the mapping.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: With that I'm just trying to emphasize that there's no simple character to character mapping, that the same character on the left can be represented by a different one on the right depending on the surrounding characters or possibly the entire left string. The question is how to find the left-string to right-string transformation/rule given a set of pairs of these strings.

Comment: @VaughnCato: I don't want to store right strings as-is. I'm hoping to find a sufficiently compact "rule". As in, 0*0=0,1*1=1,2*2=4,3*3=9 and the rule is x*x=y, no need to store actual numbers.

Comment: Would you say that the objective is to find the smallest transformation grammar that reproduces the sample mapping 80% of the time?

Comment: @VaughnCato: Yep, you can word it like that too.

Comment: It is no doubt unsolvable in general.  You mention a genetic algorithm which seems like a reasonable approach.  You can have mutation operations that add, remove, or modify productions. You can crossover operations for productions as well.  One thing that I think will be important is to have your fitness function consider the size that your grammer can be reduced to and not the actual size.  Having extra redundant productions can provide a way for mutations to affect the mapping more gradually.  You can simply the grammar before testing fitness.

Answer (score 0):

If you could align the characters, or rather groups of characters, you could work out tables saying that aa => a, bb => z, and so on. If you had such tables, you could align the characters using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping. One approach is therefore to guess an alignment (e.g. one for one, just as a starting point, or just align the first and last characters of each sequence), work out a translation table from that, use DTW to get a new alignment, work out a revised translation table, and iterate in that way. Perhaps you could wrap this up with enough maths to show that there is some measure of optimality or probability that such passes increase, climbing to a local maximum.

There is probably some way of doing this by modelling a Hidden Markov Model that generates both sequences simultaneously and then deriving rules from that model, but I would not chose this approach unless I was already familiar with HMMs and had software to use as a starting point that I was happy to modify.

Comment: Papers such as http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.9855&rep=rep1&type=pdf suggest that this is an area tricky enough to merit active research.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text to speech to create sound waves. then compare sound waves with other's and match them with percentages.

This is my theory how Google has such a advanced spell checker.

Comment: A simple spell checker only needs a list of words. Not sure how advanced Google's is, but Goggle has a lot of data and can look it up quickly. Matching sound waves is not what I need or want. It's more of the graphemes to phonemes conversion that I need and I need it without storing each "word" along with its "pronunciation".